# Run service after device was restarted

Tags: android

I want that one of my services runs even if user has restarted device. I've tried this code but didn't succeed. What should I do? Help me please.

Thank you!

MyService2.class:

```
public class MyService2 extends Service {
    private MyReceiver mR = null;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mR = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        registerReceiver(mR, intentFilter);
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
            context.startService(new Intent(context,MyService2.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First no need to register your receiver in service. Add your broadcast receiver in Manifest.

**Like :**

```
<receiver android:name="your broadcast class">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**Remember to add permission also :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

When device is rebooted your receiver will automatically get executed by system as it is declared in manifest. In your receiver just start your service.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        //add a log or toast to confirm the receive
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService2.class));
    }
}
```

}

**AND**

```
public class MyService2 extends Service {
private MyReceiver mR = null;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // do what ever you wanted to do...
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are Registering your BroadcastReciver in your Service , Which your trying to start using your BroadcastReciver which is not registered.

So try registering your broadcast Reciever in your manifest file like this

```
<receiver android:name="your broadcast class">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter
```